# Scala enqueue a string to queue within map

Tags: scala, dictionary, queue

So I have a map with two keys, left and right. Each key contains a queue. I would like to simply add to the queue based on the key. For example, in pseudocode, to add a string "item1" to the left queue:

```
m = Map("left" -> Queue(), "right" -> Queue())
m("left").enqueue("item1")
```

How can I achieve this with Scala?

Comment: Your pseudocode is essentially correct. Are you asking for help with syntax? Compiler errors?
This doesn't work with an immutable queue, so just make sure the import is `scala.collection.mutable.Queue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell the compiler what type of elements the `Queue` will hold.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Queue

val m = Map("left" -> Queue[String](), "right" -> Queue[String]())
m("left").enqueue("item1")
```

Note that `m` is type `Map[String,Queue[String]]`. For type safety all the queues need to be of the same type.